# Yaml nested replace all list, map and string values in python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I am trying to find specific values in yaml and want to replace all. I am able to replace all but unable to add as nested value.

Example :
able to identify - root key ['selector', 'matchLabels']
match key :  matchLabels  value :  <>  replacevalue :  [{'app': 'testservice', 'team': 'testing', 'contact': 'test@contact.com'}]

In my Yaml :
new_dict['selector']['matchLabels']=replacevalue
I get
new_dict['matchLabels']=replacevalue

Tried :
**if (len(rootkey) ==2):
new_dict[rootkey[0]][rootkey[1]]=replacevalue // This doesn't work**

Any help will be time saver as I am new to python.

Here is my data file

```
appname: testservice
imagerepopath: saradaimage
labels:
  - app: testservice
    team: testing #mandatory
    contact: test@contact.com #mandatory
```

Here is my yaml template

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <<appname>>
  labels:
      <<labels>>
spec:
  replicas: <<replicas>>
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        <<labels>>
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
          <<labels>>
    spec:
      containers:
          image: <<imagerepopath>>
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: accountservice
          ports:
            - containerPort: <<port>>
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 2Gi
status: {}
```

My Python able to identify the fields but can't replace value at nested :

```
import yaml
import os
from collections import defaultdict

yaml.Dumper.ignore_aliases = lambda *args : True
deploymentName = "templates/deploymenttemplate.yaml"
dataName = "k8sdata.yaml"
rootkey = []


def parseYaml(fname):
    stream = open(fname, 'r')
    return yaml.safe_load(stream)

def nested_dict_pairs_iterator(dict_obj,currentvalue,replacevalue):
    global rootkey
    # Iterate over all key-value pairs of dict argument
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():

        rootkey.append(key)

        # Check if value is of dict type
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # If value is dict then iterate over all its values
            for pair in  nested_dict_pairs_iterator(value,currentvalue,replacevalue):

                yield (key, *pair)
        else:
            # If value is not dict type then yield the value
            print("root key",rootkey)
            if (value == currentvalue) :
                print ("match key : ",key," value : ",currentvalue, " replacevalue : ",replacevalue )
                new_dict[key] = replacevalue
            else :
                print ("Unmatch key : ",key," value : ",value )
                new_dict[key] = value
            rootkey = []
            yield (key, value)



def updateDeployment(dataf):

    for datakey, datavalue in dataf.items():
        actualvalue = "<<"+datakey+">>"

        for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(deploymentf,actualvalue,datavalue):
            print("---------------------------------------------")
    print(new_dict)
    with open('temp/data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(new_dict, outfile,sort_keys=False,default_flow_style=False)


dataF = parseYaml(dataName)
deploymentf = parseYaml(deploymentName)
new_dict = defaultdict(dict)


updateDeployment(dataF)
```

Comment: Your example is confusing to read and it is not quite clear what you want to accomplish. While it may help you, showing code doing debug output and then showing us the debug output does not really help us. Try to describe or show the expected and actual result of your code instead. It is also unclear if what you show above (*new_dict['selector']['matchLabels']=replacevalue* etc) is supposed to go into your code and if so, where. Please don't split your code, show us the complete code you're executing.

Comment: Hi Flyx,  I will upload the output but I had already attached the the complete python, yaml template and yaml data file.